# Is the a way to reuse an existing Android ViewModel for iOS with KMM

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to convert an existing Android project to Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM).
A bunch of the app logic is contained in the viewmodel and I would really love to share said logic with the iOS side.
Is there a way to do that without Cocoapods integration as my iOS side was not set up with Cocoapods?

Comment: MOKO MVVM is built to solve this problem, check out [this article](https://medium.com/icerock/how-to-use-kotlin-multiplatform-viewmodel-in-swiftui-and-jetpack-compose-8158e98c091d)

Comment: I did consider this but the MOKO MVVM requires the iOS integration to be done via the CocoaPods distribution manager and not the XCode build phases like mine is set up

Comment: I believe it's not required, I suggest you create [an issue](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-mvvm/issues/new) on GitHub  and ask for a non cocoapods guide.

Answer (score 1):

Viewmodel in Android is own of framework, if you want to share presentation logic, you could use a presenter with CoroutineScope.

Answer (score 1):

You could use KMM-ViewModel.
https://github.com/rickclephas/KMM-ViewModel

Allows reusage of the Android ViewModel if put into the shared folder of your KMM project and giving each variable and function some extra annotations to let swift know how to use it.

After that you just add it to any view and use it like you would any other native ViewModel.